# How to categorize these website as non-working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been developing a program which checks whether the website is working or not. I am fetching URLs from the excel sheet and then pasting results as True(Working) & False(Non-working) in the same excel sheet but for some URLs such as **http://www.andrewelliotgroup.com/** and **https://www.sovranollc.com/**, it is showing website working but there is no data on the website. I want to filter these type of websites with no data into Non-working categories. Apart from Status code usage, what else KPI can I use to prove this. Here is the code:

```
import http.client as httpc
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import smtplib
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from xlutils import copy
import socket
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

socket.getaddrinfo('172.23.24.143', 8080)

x=[]

df = pd.read_excel (r'xyz.xlsx')
df1=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['URL'])
print(df1)
url_list=df["URL"].tolist()
print(url_list)


for i in url_list:
    def checkUrl(i):
    if 'http' not in i:
        i= 'https://'+i
    p = urlparse(i)
    if (p.scheme == 'http'):
        conn = httpc.HTTPConnection(p.netloc,timeout=15)
    else:
        conn = httpc.HTTPSConnection(p.netloc,timeout=15)
    try:
        conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
        resp = conn.getresponse()
        return resp.status<400:
    except OSError:
        return False
print(checkUrl(i))
x.append(checkUrl(i)) 

workbook = Workbook('xyz.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
Report_Sheet.write(0, 1, 'Value')
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 1, x)
Report_Sheet.write(0,0,'URL')
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 0, url_list)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Formally these sites are working unless you're receiving `Service Unavailable` error. So you're question is about filtering out sites with no data.

Comment: why don't you just check the status code instead of the content of the website?

Comment: probably cause the websites `work`(accessible) but is blank.

Comment: Yes @Alderven, I want to filter out sites with no data Status code showing website working.

Comment: You will need a definition for no data as even between the two sites you list there is a difference in the amount of html present.